# Assign colour to chosen communities in a plot

Tags: r, plot, igraph

In a plot, I need to colour two specific communities. Take the following data frame:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
C   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
E   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
F   1   1   0   1   1   0   1
G   0   0   0   0   0   1   0

ob <- read.csv("...ties.csv",sep = ",", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
m <- as.matrix(ob)
g <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="undirected", weighted = T, add.rownames = T)
```

First, I detect the communities (com) of my graph g using `edge.betweenness`:

```
com <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
V(g)$memb <- com$membership
```

This operation produces a number of communities, com[[1]],com[[2]], etc. I plot the resulting graph -- each community one colour -- with the following code:

```
plot(g, vertex.color=membership(com))
```

Now, how do I colour only two chosen communities, say com[[1]] and com[[2]], keeping the rest of the nodes homogeneous?

Comment: Show us reproducible example of your data.

Comment: I added one now. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to tweak your adjacency matrix so that more than 1 community showed up.

```
library(igraph)
ob <- read.table(text="
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
C   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
E   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
F   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
G   0   0   0   0   1   1   0", header=TRUE)

m <- as.matrix(ob)
g <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="undirected", weighted = T, add.rownames = T)
com <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
V(g)$memb <- com$membership

cols <- membership(com)  
cols[cols!=3] <- 1

plot(g, vertex.color=cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. What do 1 and 3 mean in your code? It worked, but I'm not sure what exactly happened. In my real matrix, I have 37 communities. How do I colour more than one selected community?

Comment: `cols[cols!=3] <- 1` resets the color of the "other" communities. `3` is the community I wanted to be a different color. if you wanted to color more than on communitie you could do this: `cols[!cols %in% c(1,3)] <- 1`